# Trying to read a data from another file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to make my code read the data from a different file. The data in the file `emaillist.txt` is written in the following format:

```
a
b
b
c
s
f
s
```

Now I am tryin to pick a random email from this file and I am getting an error.
Here is the code {Note: this is a piece of code, I have imported the correct libraries}:

```
with open('emaillist.txt') as emails:
                read_emails = csv.reader(emails, delimiter = '\n')
        for every_email in read_emails:
                return random.choice(every_email)
```

and this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "codeOffshoreupdated.py", line 56, in <module>
    'email': email_random(),
  File "codeOffshoreupdated.py", line 12, in email_random
    for every_email in read_emails:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Can you please help me fix it? It will be very helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you edit your example to make it runnable? It has an indentation error and appears to be part of a function. I created a test from your code and it did not have an I/O failure. It did have a bug - it always returns "a".

Comment: yes, I just fixed this I/O error but you are right. I always get a only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will return you a random email from the emilas that in the file because in your code is returning the first email from the file since it is the first iteration of `for every_email in read_emails:`

```
with open('emaillist.txt') as emails:
     read_emails = csv.reader(emails, delimiter = '\n')
     return random.choice(list(read_emails))[0]
```

Comment: Let me try it. But can you please explain why it does return only the first email from the list?

Comment: Because for "every_email in read_emails: return random.choice(every_email)" it's doing random of the first email in the files email like doing random.choice([1])

Comment: I am getting this error now "TypeError: object of type '_csv.reader' has no len()
"

Comment: I get it, thank you. But ia am getting another error now

Comment: Yes, it works. But again, it gives an error sometimes "IndexError: list index out of range
" Is it because I used a blank space in the list?

Comment: maybe the [0] is not necessary. let me know if it's working without it.

Comment: without [0], it returns the data like this [a]

Comment: So it maybe because of the black spaces in the file.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will remove them. I dont really need blank spaces in my file. Also can you please explain what was the error and how did you fix it?

Comment: The error was that he read_email param was out of the with open(file) as: and because of that when you tried to iterate over it the file was closed.

Answer (score 1):

Indent your for loop, like this:

```
with open('emaillist.txt') as emails:
                read_emails = csv.reader(emails, delimiter = '\n')
                for every_email in read_emails:
                        return random.choice(every_email)
```

Comment: Thank you and I understand now what was the issue. But I still do not get a random email address from the list. I get the first email in the list only. can you please tell me what is this issue?